# Fit two intersecting straight lines in Mathematica

Tags: fitting

I am trying to do a *Kurie analysis* of the double beta decay of *Strontium-90*.

[image]

Here we have two straight sections, and I need to obtain a value for the intersection along with an error for it. I cannot fit the linear sections separately and use gaussian error propagation, since the fit parameters are correlated, which leads to a wrong result.

My idea was to fit the entire data with one function which is defined piecewise, since the intersection parameter would then not be correlated to the others.

However, after several attempts and a fine looking fit, *Mathematica* reports an error of `0`.

```
NonlinearModelFit[data, (a*x + b)*UnitStep[x + k] + (c*x + d)*UnitStep[k - x], 
  {{a, -6.5}, {b, 3}, {c, -1}, {d, 1.8}, {k, 0.55}}, x, Method -> "NMinimize"]
```

[image]

Are there any other ways of doing this?

---

As requested in the comments:

```
data = {
   {2.160471686147928`, 0.14147102932224526`},{2.0826390189609363`,0.19988842616357125`},
   {2.018773794495269`, 0.2541246545339056`}, {1.9476326649797793`, 0.3042648279519891`},
   {1.8745330031773189`, 0.3792877696740006`}, {1.8048469776435923`, 0.4333264807298175`},
   {1.731446650327849`, 0.4855243148263505`}, {1.6651014082972075`, 0.5645773920773384`},
   {1.5932847071615477`, 0.5972837751080117`}, {1.52139595538298`, 0.6653922271670848`},
   {1.4422671545128036`, 0.7171604890149067`}, {1.3757137824715229`, 0.79262676502781`},
   {1.3073786844775914`, 0.8404843652309524`}, {1.2337051064574602`, 0.8954499357694174`},
   {1.1906240113139641`, 0.9399196660012136`}, {1.1601352767466366`, 0.9890482524748053`},
   {1.0867224338785175`, 1.0227388598388758`}, {1.0206577309807057`, 1.0542107134579233`},
   {0.9477230432778146`, 1.1301493061594161`}, {0.8733917792374216`, 1.1877273944557323`},
   {0.8065623408414323`, 1.2154971541338453`}, {0.736758267792002`, 1.3121152330650923`},
   {0.6676435767247085`, 1.3823323706871722`}, {0.635101745155093`, 1.3868057675840053`},
   {0.599382518347645`, 1.4179592728730186`}, {0.5622741608125342`, 1.4536070008301036`},
   {0.5321771084417978`, 1.4636936970264636`}, {0.490818693322041`, 1.6204857554395113`},
   {0.4613963222976981`, 1.6851063997905946`}, {0.42109009911055906`,1.8551603288963705`},
   {0.39567303637157025`, 1.945847339995944`}, {0.36747227092332413`, 2.145514603636669`},
   {0.34125816875918824`, 2.333372509561687`}, {0.3124933023702082`, 2.347039270807089`}};
```

Comment: The problem is, that NLMFit does not calculate an error for the parameter k. I need to quantify exactly this error.

Comment: Data would be nice.

Comment: I would estimate an error from the distance between closest to `k` data points .

Comment: Data is at https://www.dropbox.com/s/kt7fmk3p96uu1yk/kurie-uncorrected.csv

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Something strange happens when you allow your lines in your model to have a gap at point k. You also specified UnitStep functions wrongly - see my version below. You do realize your model function allows for gap?

It is better to have less parameters in the model. Obviously your data assume that lines meet without gap. Why not to explicitly specify this excluding one parameter?

```
Solve[a*x + b == c x + d /. x -> k, d]
```

> {{d -> b + a k - c k}}

Now your model is

```
g[x_, a_, b_, c_, k_] := 
(a x + b) UnitStep[k - x] + (c x + (b + a k - c k)) UnitStep[x - k]
```

But I would better define it as:

```
g[x_, a_, b_, c_, k_] := 
Piecewise[{{a x + b, x < k}, {b + (a - c) k + c x, x >= k}}]
```

Using your data:

```
nlm = NonlinearModelFit[data, 
  g[x, a, b, c, k], {{a, -3.5}, {b, 3.5}, {c, -1}, {k, 0.5}}, x];

Plot[nlm[x], {x, 0, 3}, Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[.01], Point@data}, 
 Frame -> True, Axes -> False]
```

[image]

```
nlm["ParameterTable"]
```

[image]

Comment: The problem is that the residuals don't change continuously with respect to changes in k.

Comment: @MichaelE2 you mean the problem with his model function?

Comment: @VitaliyKaurov Yes, that's what I mean.  A sufficiently small change in `k` makes no change in the fitting errors.

Comment: @MichaelE2 What you are saying then is that it is not possible to fit a discontinuous function?

Comment: @VitaliyKaurov  In some sense.  There is still a value of `k` that minimizes the error.  In fact, though, there will be an interval of values.  The discontinuous nature makes finding the minimum somewhat challenging.  swish's comment to the question has some merit in this regard.

Comment: I would add that as a problem in probability, estimating the error in `k` is beyond my understanding of probability and statistics.  One might take as a point estimate the midpoint of the interval of values for `k` that minimizes the error.  But I have no idea how such a statistic is distributed.

Comment: @VitaliyKaurov No, I had not realized that the way I defined the function allows for the lines to not meet directly, but are completely correct, and I realized where the mistake in my thought was.

Comment: My comments deal with the OP's model and not Vitaliy's, I am afraid they might be misinterpreted.  I was going to delete them, when one was upvoted....So maybe they're not useless. +1 to VK, though.

Comment: @MichaelE2 I upvoted your comment for considering the problem under probability framework. But I also +1 for Vitaliy's solution as OP's data has very small deviation so the method of least squares should be unbiased and thus applicable.